# Refresh a access token with google analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics

I try to refresh an access token with the google analytics API (php) but I've always the **invalid_grant error** ... that's my process:

**1. I save a first acces token in my database with a offline request, the response is:**

```
{"access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZSPMUyKfx06Bw89LnlfRa5mEmwdthyCUj6D7bRmDcQ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"1\/1XLO8PLs2Pb0NPs-T-lt07jWW_STBWYG3IGRB08ZbkA","created":1338810086}
```

**2. I check the token info, if "expires_in" < 0 i try to refresh my token:**

```
if ($infoAt['expires_in'] <= 0) {
 $row = $database->loadObject("SELECT refresh from token WHERE id=1");
 $client->refreshToken($row['refresh']);
}
```

and I've a invalid_grant error ...

any help ?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english ...

Comment: is $row['refresh '] supposed to be with space in the end?

Comment: No sorry, but in my original code there isn't white space ...

Comment: As I understand, refresh tokens are used for getting new token. That is, the old one expires and you get the new one. If I get it correctly, $client->refreshToken() returns new token, which you should save to db (?). Sorry if I'm wrong, I didn't look at the client library itself

Comment: Yes, you got it :) but the refreshToken method return an "invalid grant" error ...

Comment: I fixed the bug but I dont know what was wrong. The refresh token generated wasn't valide. So I used the [google oauthplayground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) for generating a refresh token and now it works fine :)

Comment: you can answer your own question. don't let it be (and sit) 'unanswered' like this! ;-)

Comment: @user1435254, hi how did you get the `expires_in` and where did you place it in your code, any hint will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: @mongotop here my code: http://snipt.org/wRhc2

Comment: @shinework, Thanks for the link! highly appreciated! will be great if you post that code as an answer! Thanks!  M