# Google Analytics access token expired after 3600 s (1 hour)

Tags: php, authentication, terminal, access-token, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google analytics API (PHP) to retrieve my account info, I retrieved the refrech token using :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {

// echo $_SESSION['token'].'<br />';

$authObj = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
$refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
$tokenType = $authObj->token_type;
$expiresIn = $authObj->expires_in;

echo 'access_token = ' . $accessToken;
echo '<br />';
echo 'refresh_token = ' . $refreshToken;
echo '<br />';
echo 'token_type = ' . $tokenType;
echo '<br />';
echo 'expires_in = ' . $expiresIn;
echo '<br />';
}
```

after that I copied the value returned by `$refreshToken`, I comment the previous function and I call the method as following:

```
$refreshToken  = '1/YZiV9J********vMjey8*****************';
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
```

This works perfect, but it through an error after an hour telling me that the access token has been exprired.

How can I know that the access token is expired, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882294/refresh-a-access-token-with-google-analytics-api), the guy solve his problem but he didn't post the answer. 
and how can I generate a new one using the same refrech token without going through the authorization process again because I'm running my code through the terminal.

I posted bellow a snippet from my project.

Thanks!

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
$scriptUri = 'http://domainname.com';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Analytics project');

$client->setClientId('************.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('S**********************1T');

$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);

$client->setDeveloperKey('**************************-1c');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

$client->setAccessType('offline'); 
$client->setUseObjects(true);


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {  
$client->authenticate();  
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 

$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {    
$authObj = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
$refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
$tokenType = $authObj->token_type;
$expiresIn = $authObj->expires_in;
}


if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {  

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();  
print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
} else {  
// Create analytics service object. See next step below.
$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
runMainDemo($analytics);
}




function runMainDemo(&$analytics) {  

try {    
// Step 2. Get the user's first profile ID.    
$profileId = getProfileId($analytics);    
if (isset($profileId)) {      
    // Step 3. Query the Core Reporting API.      
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profileId);      
    // Step 4. Output the results.      
    printResults($results);    
    }  
} 
catch (apiServiceException $e) {    
// Error from the API.    
print 'There was an API error : ' . $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();  
} 
catch (Exception $e) {    
print 'There wan a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();  
}
}



function getProfileId(&$analytics) {
    //My code to retrieve data
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response contains how long the token is good for. So it's up to you to store the expiry, and check it before making the request.

In psuedocode:

```
$expiry = getDate().now + $expires_in;
//later
if(getDate().now > $expiry) {
   //our token is expired. get a new one
}
```

The only way to avoid going through the auth process again locally is to have a server proxy the auth request for you, and returning the result to your client. By proxy the request, you basically have a webapp server sitting somewhere (heroku, engineyard, ec2, your backyard w/e), and you send it the request for a token. It in turn makes the auth request to google, gets the new token, and returns that result back to you.

The whole point of this is to force you to reauth periodically for security reasons. If there was a way to by-pass it, it wouldn't be very secure.

Comment: Hi Alan, your code Looks Great! Where should I place your code, and what I should be put between the if statement brackets? Thanks!

Comment: It's pseudo code, not real code. In the if statement, you'll need to make another call to google to get a new token.

Answer (score -2):

This was my solution!

```
function getProfileId(&$analytics) {
    
      for ($i=0;i<10;$i++){
           
             **My code to retrieve data**
             // I called the method 'refreshToken' as following

             $GLOBALS['client']->refreshToken($GLOBALS['refreshToken']); 
       }
}
```

$GLOBALS is for to call an outside variable, check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) out for more info about how $GLOBALS works.

So everytime I go through the loop I generate a new access token so I never run out  of access token.